# Convert table to hierarchical vs linear

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking if exists for any standard functions in PHP to change a tabular array into a deeper grouped array as below:

```
$table = [
    [1, "group1", "Name 1", "Value 1"]
    , [2, "group1", "Name 2", "Value 2"]
    , [3, "group1", "Name 3", "Value 3"]
    , [4, "group1", "Name 4", "Value 4"]
    , [5, "group2", "Name 5", "Value 5"]
    , [6, "group2", "Name 6", "Value 6"]
    , [7, "group2", "Name 7", "Value 7"]
];

$table_result = [
    "group1" =>
        [
            [1, "Name 1", "Value 1"]
            , [2, "Name 2", "Value 2"]
            , [3, "Name 3", "Value 3"]
            , [4, "Name 4", "Value 4"]
        ]
    , "group2" =>
        [
            [5, "Name 5", "Value 5"]
            , [6, "Name 6", "Value 6"]
            , [7, "Name 7", "Value 7"]
        ]
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a signle function, but it's quite simple :

```
foreach ($table as $v) {
    $table_result[$v[1]][] = array($v[0], $v[2], $v[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am little bit late. Maybe this function can help you :

```
function Group($table, $groupELm, array $hArr=[]){
    $temp   = null;
    if(empty($table)) return $hArr;
    $hArr = empty($hArr)?[]:$hArr;
    if(isset($hArr[$table[0][$groupELm]]))
    {
        $temp       = $table;
        unset($table[0][$groupELm]);
        $hArr[$temp[0][$groupELm]][] = $table[0];
    }else{
        $temp       = $table;
        unset($table[0][$groupELm]);
        $hArr[$temp[0][$groupELm]] = array();
        $hArr[$temp[0][$groupELm]][] = $table[0];

    }
    array_shift($table);
    $hArr   = fun($table, $groupELm, $hArr);
    return $hArr;
    }
```

Usage :

```
Group($table, 1); // where 1 is key of index that you want to match
```

In Your case :

```
$table = [
            [1, "group1", "Name 1", "Value 1"],
            [2, "group1", "Name 2", "Value 2"],
            [3, "group1", "Name 3", "Value 3"],
            [4, "group1", "Name 4", "Value 4"],
            [5, "group2", "Name 5", "Value 5"],
            [6, "group2", "Name 6", "Value 6"],
            [7, "group2", "Name 7", "Value 7"]
];


print_r(Group($table, 1));
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [group1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [2] => Name 1
                    [3] => Value 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [2] => Name 2
                    [3] => Value 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [2] => Name 3
                    [3] => Value 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [2] => Name 4
                    [3] => Value 4
                )

        )

    [group2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [2] => Name 5
                    [3] => Value 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [2] => Name 6
                    [3] => Value 6
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7
                    [2] => Name 7
                    [3] => Value 7
                )

        )

)
```